# GWT download byte[]

Tags: gwt, resty-gwt

Can you help me I have PDF file in byte[]
I get it from resty-gwt

```
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })

    @Path("/report")
    @POST
    void report(String id, JsonCallback jsonCallback);
```

So I have JSON

```
{
    "report": "..."
    }
```

How can I download it???

Comment: Do you wish to do it at the server side or the client side?

Comment: It will be super if it work only on client side!!!

Comment: Can anybody help me?